# any tools of create kml string for google-maps-v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-maps-api-3

i want to generate some kml string to stroe into database ..

and has any simply way to generate this string ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean kml string, isnt it an xml file like the one below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Stonehenge, England</name>
    <description>Stonehenge was built about 2500BC
    </description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-1.826752,51.179045
      </coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark> 
</kml>
```

In which case you can use

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
```

etc

Comment: yes , and i want to find "KML Interactive Sampler" for google-maps(not earth)

Comment: What format will the string that you want to store in the database take?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this digitizer tool

http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/googletool.html